# TypeError in if/else function accessing nested object

Tags: javascript, nested

```js
var customerData = { 
  'Joe': {visits: 1},
  'Carol': {visits: 2},
  'Howard': {visits: 3},
  'Carrie': {visits: 4}
};

function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var greeting = '';
  var token = customerData[firstName];
  var value = token['visits'];
  if (firstName in customerData === false) {
    greeting = 'Welcome! Is this your first time?';
  } else if (value === 1) {
    greeting = 'Welcome back, ' + firstName + ', We\'re glad you liked us the first time!';
  } else if (value > 1) {
    greeting = 'Welcome back, ' + firstName + '! So glad to see you again!'
  }
  return greeting;
}

console.log(greetCustomer('Nobody'));
```

Three conditions in this if/else function. The only condition that didn't pass the tests is the first one. Really have no idea why, because the logic looks legit. I suspect it has to do with accessing the nested object bit, but can't figure out how.

Comment: Try adding parentheses around your "firstName in customerData". Currently, you are doing (firstName in (customerData === false)), which is evaluating to a boolean. e.g. ``ìf ((firstName in customerData) === false)``

Comment: Ignore this - it was just a hunch, but I just realised that your "token" variable is undefined. See answer below. Nothing to see here!

Comment: If "token" is undefined, how can I make it defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you just need to rearrange your logic. If the name does not exist in the object then your token variable will be null and your application will break when you try to reference a property of that null object. After trying to get your token value, if it is null then welcome the new person. If not null then continue your logic for existing persons.

```js
var customerData = { 
  'Joe': {visits: 1},
  'Carol': {visits: 2},
  'Howard': {visits: 3},
  'Carrie': {visits: 4}
};

function greetCustomer(firstName) {
  var token = customerData[firstName];
  if (token == null) {
    return 'Welcome! Is this your first time?';
  } else {
    var value = token['visits'];
    if (value === 1) {
      return 'Welcome back, ' + firstName + ', We\'re glad you liked us the first time!';
    } else if (value > 1) {
      return 'Welcome back, ' + firstName + '! So glad to see you again!'
    }
  }
  return '';
}

console.log(greetCustomer('Nobody'));
```

Comment: You code passed all the tests. It's an issue with the Repl. I tried your code on https://repl.it/languages/javascript. Curiously, the app told me to use '===' instead of '==' for the 'null' part in the first condition. When I made that change, the same error came up again.

Comment: That is because === means EXACTLY equal. customerData[firstName] produced `undefined` so when compared to null it does not evaluate to true and enters the else statement. When using ==, null == undefined. If you wish to use ===, then change `(token == null)` to `(token === undefined)`.

Comment: A better definition of the issue you just pointed out is "The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.". So when you used ===, it was comparing undefined to null which is not equal.